# Delphi 2010 How to do something on form startup without requiring the user to take some action ( Button click, etc..)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How to do something on form startup like :

```
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add('sorry email@exemple.com is already in our database');
```

NOT untill the user take some action ( Button click, etc..)

I tried with the code below and it works but i am obliged to click on the button one in order to add that line into the richEdit1 compenent.

Comment: Did you try the `OnCreate` event for that form?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what exactly you mean by 'NOT until user take some action'. Can you try to explain your problem with a bit more detail? Also, you mention this "I tried with the code below", but I don't see that code.

Comment: You want to delay adding the line "until the user take some action (button click)", but you don't like to be "obliged to click on the button". It sounds contradictory. Please explain better the scenario of the actions you want the user to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `OnActivate` event of the form to set properties for visual controls. I usually do it as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Allow this code to run only once
  OnActivate := nil;

  //Set RichEdit Properties
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add('sorry email@exemple.com is already in our database');
end;
```

Comment: That is what 'OnActivate := nil;' is for. 'OnActivate' will only be called once.

Answer (score 3):

If the `TRichEdit` control has been added at design time to a form, then you can set the properties of the RichEdit control in the form's `OnCreate` event.

This allows you to set the properties of controls before the user even sees the controls or has a chance to interact with them.

`OnCreate` is called after the form is created (including child controls) and before it's shown.

To open the OnCreate event for editing in the IDE, you can simply double-click on an empty part of the form.

Answer (score 2):

Use the OnShow event of the form.

BUT: use a private field FShown : boolean, and test it in your OnShow handler - if it is TRUE, exit immediately.

if it is FALSE, then set it to TRUE and proceed with whatever you want to do.

There's also the OnCreate event, but in many cases that is too early - many visual components have not been properly initialized yet when code in OnCreate handler is running.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it is necessary to delay actions until the message loop has started running.  In those situations, I tend to use the form's constructor or `OnCreate` event to post a custom asynchronous message to the form's window via `PostMessage()` (some people use a short-interval `TTimer` instead), and then perform the action in the form's `WndProc()` method when the message has been received.